# Erase a 1st gen iPad

Tags: ipad, ipsw

I have a 1st gen iPad that I don't know the passcode for. iTunes tells me that I need to enter the passcode before I can use it with iTunes.

So I followed some instructions and put the iPad into Recovery mode, which let me connect to iTunes and hit the Restore button.

iTunes apparently will not let me just restore the iPad using the iOS version it currently has; instead it demands that I let it download a new iOS version first.

But my internet is so slow and unreliable where I live now that I have not been able to get iTunes to finish downloading.

So I found a website that lets you download IPSW's.  I downloaded 5.1 for iPad 1st gen. I then held Option while clicking Restore in iTunes, chose this IPSW file, and iTunes told me it is not valid.

So....
Questions:

1. Is there any way I can use this iPad as-is without knowing the passcode?
2. Is there any way I can restore it without downloading any huge IPSW files?
3. If not, is there any other way I can get rid of the passcode or wipe the device clean?
4. I welome jailbreaking and 3rd-party software in my quest...

Answer (score 2):

The iPad 1 should be good to go for a valid version of 5.1.1

- http://www.icj.me/ios/all#iPad11

I'd say the easiest thing to do would be to take the iPad to a copy of iTunes that has a good internet connection or download a reputable copy (for whatever reputable means to you) of 5.1.1 IPSW and use your iTunes to wipe and restore the iPad.

Jailbreaking might be an option, but I'd go with easy.

Comment: Unfortunately I will not have access to a good internet connection for at least a month.

Comment: That is unfortunate. With the device locked, you surely won't be able to jailbreak it (and those tools are on the internet as well). Perhaps a friend could mail you a USB drive with the file downloaded?

Comment: Any progress after a month, @themirror ?

Answer (score 0):

Enter the wrong passcode 10 times to erase the device. Later in the process, like after try 6 the wait starts to get longer before it will let you try again. After erasing the device you will be able to set it up with your Apple ID.